# How can i find this strange directory in Docker (com.docker.devenvironments.code)

Tags: docker

I'd like to know if someone had my same problem while creating the Dev Environment in Docker. The first time i've created the Dev Environment in macOS, no problem. From the second time, i'm having this error (destination path '/com.docker.devenvironments.code' already exists and is not an empty directory.) while pointing to Path to my Download directory (Screen at the bottom).

I've searched everywhere but i cannot find this directory. Tried also to reinstall docker and purge all is data. Can someone please help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkT50.png)